# How do I omit an element from an array type, such as Parameters<T>?

Tags: typescript

Example, assuming `make` is a function defined elsewhere.

```js
create(...args: Parameters<typeof make>): ReturnType<typeof make> {
    return make(firstArgument, ...args);
}
```

What can I wrap `Parameters<typeof make>` in to omit the first element of its array type, so I can define `create`'s signature as the *remaining* arguments to `make`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```js
type OmitFirst<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : never
```

Then you can use `OmitFirst<Parameters<typeof make>>` in your function's signature.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQQJwM7ADwBUoQAewEAdgCYZQCGpIA2gLoB8UAvFPkSRVfbSAA0UAHRiEpAGYQ0UAEqMoAfnlQAXFFIQAbjIBQeyQFdSAY2AIA9qShxqAawgAKQhtJG4AIxnCQGrGgSAObCAF4anpaWADYQtACUGtqWCORQAN4GAL4GxmYW1lCmaHEkTmIi1GhBGBrwSKiYOAAKVdRwECSY2KCQlpK2DhDMzInynUZopLjgED2z-YOOrJlQa1AlwJM2do5OAKzCFVU18QDcejlAA)

Comment: For what it's worth, in functional programming this operation is usually called [`Tail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tail)